# Laravel 5.3 + Sentinel: BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2450

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3, sentinel

I'm trying to build my first Laravel application by following a few guides on the internet and I'm feeling I'm missing something obvious. Here is the code.

**Error**

> BadMethodCallException in Builder.php line 2450: Call to undefined
>   method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::addresses()

**User-Model**

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Sentinel;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 
        'remember_token'
    ];

    public function addresses()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\CustomerAddress');
    }
}
```

**CustomerAddress-model**

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class CustomerAddress extends Model
{
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

**CustomerAddress-controller**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\CustomerAddress;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class CustomerAddressController extends Controller
{
    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $address = new CustomerAddress();
        $address->address = $request['address'];
        $request->user()->addresses()->save($address);
    }
}
```

Error appears after this piece of code:

```
$request->user()->addresses()->save($address);
```

Any ideas? Thanks and cheers

Comment: You need to $address->save() before request->user()->addresses()->save($address);

Comment: Also use $request->input('address')

Comment: There should also be a user_id field on the customer_address table

Comment: Hey, thanks for a fast reply. adding $address->save() gives another error message and there is a column in the customer_address table "Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `customer_addresses` (`address`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (asdasd, 2016-12-24 02:54:34, 2016-12-24 02:54:34))", even after adding the "address" to fillables in CustomerAddress-model.

Comment: Try $request->user()->addresses()->associate($address); instead let's see

Comment: Because what you have now should automatically insert the user_id in the customer_address table given that the $request->user() is valid

Comment: Oh wait...one user can have multiple addresses?

Comment: Mr. Google told me to turn off strict mode in the config/database.php and it did work, well almost. The "address" is now saved to the database with timestaps, however the user_id is always assigned 0 (which is not correct current user id). I also now get the first errror again with Builder:addresses

Comment: Yeah that will no work because you are trying to create a related model with a one to many relationship

Comment: I would suggest getting rid of your last line of code above and just adding $address->user_id = $request->user()->id and then save()

Comment: Wooho, the above worked, thanks a lot. I'm now however a bit lost in the code and have no idea what's going. I guess we manually assign the user_id field, which means the relations are not really helpful?

Comment: They are and I'm not exactly sure what's going on here. You should try using Auth::user()->addresses()->save($address); See if that works, $request user might not be hooking into the eloquent model proper

Comment: Could it have something to do with me using Sentinel? I'm was suspecting it from the beginning that's why i included it in the question tags.

Comment: Did Auth::user() work?

Comment: After adding "use Auth" in the controller, no. "Call to a member function addresses() on null"

Comment: Dont users log in to update their address ?

Comment: If they don't then that's the problem

Comment: And no I don't believe it has anything to do with Sentinel. From what you posted, it's not being used by the User model

Comment: They are / i am. However I'm not using laravel's standard package for authentication.

Comment: Well i'm using Sentinel to authenticate users.

Comment: Then $user = Sentinel::getUser() will get you the authenticated users instance. So $user->addresses()->save($address); should work...at least it makes sense

Comment: Yeha that would make sense and i believe i have tried that before as i did now again to confirm. However it gives me the same Builder error as before.

$user = Sentinel::getUser();
$address = new CustomerAddress();
$address->address = $request['address'];
$user->addresses()->save($address);

Comment: So weird, try $request->user->addresses()->save($address); without the () on user. My last attempt to salvage this

Comment: If you want and have time to check out the full source code, here is the full project repo. It's really small with only a few routes. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/42704655/firstapp.rar

Comment: Unfortunately i get the "Call to a member function addresses() on null" error with the above code. It's 5 AM so I'll go to bed now. Thanks for your attempt. I'll obviously check this thread out when i wake up. Cheers and thanks again for your effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- In .config/cartalyst.sentinel.php, change `'model' => 'Cartalyst\Sentinel\Users\EloquentUser'` to `'model' => 'App\User'` to use your user model with the `addresses` relation defined
- In ./app/User change `User extends Authenticatable` to `User extends \Cartalyst\Sentinel\Users\EloquentUser` to extend sentinel's user to your app's User model
- Finally, your controller code should now be

`$address = new CustomerAddress();
 $address->address = $request->input('address');

$request->user()->addresses()->save($address);`

and everything should be peachy

Comment: Hey! The above is working for me, however I have a question related to the last piece of code. Why do i need to first save the addresses in the table ($address->save()) and then add user_id to it by $request->user()->addresses()->save($address)? Doesn't this result in face in two (2) insert queries getting executed? It also works just fine for me without $address->save(). Cheers and thanks!

Comment: Also inserting everything at once doesn't requie the nullable property of user_id in the table. I don't know, i might just be missing something important here.

Comment: You are right, adding $address->save() is why I needed user_id to be nullable. It should work fine without user_id being nullable if you remove $address->save(). I hope this clears it up

Comment: Great! Maybe I'm getting catch of it after all. Thanks again for your help. Cheers!